# Что значит ошибка unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QLineEdit' and 'int';?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, случайные-числа, qlineedit

Начал делать рандомайзер (для общего развитие). Все хорошо, код написал, проверяю и выдает такую ошибку:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'QLineEdit' and 'int';

Вот мой код:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
import random

app = QApplication([])
win = QWidget()
win.resize(400, 550)
win.setWindowTitle('Randomizer')

txt = QLabel('<b> Randomizer </b>')
first_num = QLineEdit('')
second_num = QLineEdit('')
first_lbl = QLabel('Initial number: ')
second_lbl = QLabel('Final number: ')
ans = QLabel('')
bt1 = QPushButton('Get Number')

line = QVBoxLayout()

line.addWidget(txt)
txt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
line.addStretch(1)
line.addWidget(first_lbl)
first_lbl.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
line.addStretch(1)
line.addWidget(first_num)
first_num.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
line.addStretch(1)
line.addWidget(second_lbl)
first_lbl.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
line.addStretch(1)
line.addWidget(second_num)
first_num.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft | Qt.AlignTop)
line.addStretch(1)
line.addWidget(ans)
ans.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
line.addStretch(1)
line.addWidget(bt1, Qt.AlignCenter)
line.addStretch(2)

def click():
    rand = str(random.randint(first_num, second_num))
    ans.setText(rand)

bt1.clicked.connect(click)
win.setLayout(line)
win.show()
app.exec_()
```

Если можете, то помогите решить проблему.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> random.randint(a, b)
>
> Возвращает случайное целое число N такое, что a <= N <= b.

`first_num` и `first_num` - это объекты `QLineEdit`. 
Чтобы получить из этих объектов содержимое, т.е. строку надо выполнить

```
first_num = self.first_num.text()
second_num = self.second_num.text()
```

которую (**`строку`**) надо преобразовать в целое число  (**`int()`**)

```
    rand = str(random.randint(
        int(self.first_num.text()), 
        int(self.second_num.text())
    ))
```

---

```
import random
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.txt = QLabel('<b> Randomizer </b>')
        self.txt.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.first_num = QLineEdit()
        self.second_num = QLineEdit()
        
        self.first_lbl = QLabel('Initial number: ')
        self.second_lbl = QLabel('Final number: ')
        
        self.ans = QLabel()
        self.ans.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ans.setStyleSheet('color: #f55; font-size: 32px;')
        
        self.bt1 = QPushButton('Get Number')
        self.bt1.clicked.connect(self._click)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.txt)
        layout.addWidget(self.first_lbl)
        layout.addWidget(self.first_num)
        layout.addWidget(self.second_lbl)
        layout.addWidget(self.second_num)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(self.ans)
        layout.addStretch(1)
        layout.addWidget(self.bt1, Qt.AlignCenter)

    def _click(self):
        first_num = self.first_num.text()
        second_num = self.second_num.text() 
        
        if not first_num or not second_num:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'Заполните поля ввода.')
            return
        if first_num > second_num:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Внимание', 'first_num > second_num.')
            return
            
    #    rand = str(random.randint(first_num, second_num))
        rand = str(random.randint(int(self.first_num.text()), int(self.second_num.text())))
        self.ans.setText(rand)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(400, 350)
    w.setWindowTitle('Randomizer')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ :)

Comment: @L1nkoln пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour